# Function that compares one column values against all other column values and returns matching one in R

Tags: r

So let's say I have two data frames

```
df1 <- data.frame(n = rep(n = 2,c(0,1,2,3,4)), nn =c(rep(x = 1, 5), rep(x=2, 5)),
                  y = rnorm(10), z = rnorm(10)) 

df2 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(20))
```

Here is the first df:

```
 > head(df1)
      n nn          y           z
    1 0  1  1.5683647  0.48934096
    2 1  1  1.2967556 -0.77891030
    3 2  1 -0.2375963  1.74355935
    4 3  1 -1.2241501 -0.07838729
    5 4  1 -0.3278127 -0.97555379
    6 0  2 -2.4124503  0.07065982
```

Here is the second df:

```
         x
1 -0.4884289
2  0.9362939
3 -1.0624084
4 -0.9838209
5  0.4242479
6 -0.4513135
```

I'd like to substact x column values of df2 from z column values of df1. And return the rows of both dataframes for which the substracted value is approximately equal to that of y value of df1.
Is there a way to construct such function, so that I could imply the approximation to which the values should be equal?
So, that it's clear, I'd like to substract all x values from all z values and then compare the value to y column value of df1, and check if there is approximately matching value to y.

Comment: Could you show us your code that you have so far?

Comment: @intedgar I showed all I got. I have two dataframes and I'd like to apply an operation to all possible values of both df columns and then the resulting vector compare to y column of df1.

Comment: You need to `set.seed(123)` or otherwise your random data is going to be different every time for your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach where I match every row of `df1` with every row of `df2`, then take x and y from z (as implied by your logic of comparing z-x to y; this is the same as comparing z-x-y to zero). Finally, I look at each row of df1 and keep the match with the lowest absolute difference.

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(
    df1 %>% mutate(dummy = 1, row = row_number()),
    df2 %>% mutate(dummy = 1, row = row_number()), by = "dummy") %>%
    mutate(diff = z - x - y) %>%
    group_by(row.x) %>%
    slice_min(abs(diff)) %>%
    ungroup()
```

Result (I used `set.seed(42)` before generating `df1`+`df2`.)

```
# A tibble: 10 x 9
       n    nn       y      z dummy row.x       x row.y    diff
   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <int>   <dbl>
 1     0     1  1.37    1.30      1     1  0.0361    20 -0.102 
 2     1     1 -0.565   2.29      1     2  1.90       5  0.956 
 3     2     1  0.363  -1.39      1     3 -1.76       8  0.0112
 4     3     1  0.633  -0.279     1     4 -0.851     18 -0.0607
 5     4     1  0.404  -0.133     1     5 -0.609     14  0.0713
 6     0     2 -0.106   0.636     1     6  0.705     12  0.0372
 7     1     2  1.51   -0.284     1     7 -1.78       2 -0.0145
 8     2     2 -0.0947 -2.66      1     8 -2.41      19 -0.148 
 9     3     2  2.02   -2.44      1     9 -2.41      19 -2.04  
10     4     2 -0.0627  1.32      1    10  1.21       4  0.168
```